# UTF-8 For Restful Services

Tags: cxf, jax-rs

Currently i enable UTF-8 as @Consumes("application/xml;charset=utf-8") in the RESTful Services for the different methods. I am interested to see if we can change this for all REST services with a single configuration change. We are using CXF, maybe there is something it provides?

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 1):

The first question is are you sure you want to prevent any of your rest resources from accepting non-UTF-8 entities? Such an across the board proclamation feels like it could cause trouble down the road.

I'll admit that I haven't used CXF so I can't speak to those specifics. But I can think of one option each under the JAX-RS and Servlet APIs which might be along the lines of what you seek to accomplish.

Using the Servlet API: Depending on how you are deploying your application you might be able to create and inject a [servlet filter](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html). In the doFilter method, you can check the encoding of the request entity and continue on to the next part of the filter chain (ultimately to the rest application). If an improper entity is sent on the request, you would just set the appropriate HTTP 415 status onto the response and not invoke your rest application.

Using JAX-RS: Depending on how you parse/accept the entity body in your resources, you could create and inject a custom [MessageBodyReader](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) implementation. This reader could parse your entity, ensuring that it is UTF-8 only and throw an appropriate exception otherwise.